# É possível saber o número de linhas que um texto ocupa em um <p>?

Tags: php

Eu preciso disso para alguns laços condicionais, mas não tenho ideia de como fazer, ou se é possível.

Supondo que tenho uma `string`, e que preciso saber quantas linhas ela ocuparia em um determinado parágrafo (`<p>`), só que não pode ser calculado no front-end (js), tem que ser no back, no php.

Alguém sabe uma função em que eu possa passar o tamanho Width mais a string, e ela retornar o total de linhas?

algo como

```
<?php 
   function nmrLinhas(width, string){
         (faz o processo) 
        return linhas; 
   }
?>
```

Caso não tenha ficado muito claro, por favor, perguntem que tentarei esclarecer.

Comment: A resposta simplificada é não, não dá pois você não tem controle sobre as configurações de fonte do usuário final. Na prática, até daria para estimar se você usar a mesma fonte no servidor e simular um render dela, e isto se já souber a largura final do <p> ao ser renderizado do lado do cliente, mas está longe de ser uma tarefa simples. É imensa a quantidade de coisas que pode fugir do seu controle neste processo, a começar pelo renderer de cada browser poder ter variação. Um pixel de diferença em cada caso pode mudar totalmente o lugar das quebras automáticas de linha.

Comment: `substr_count($texto, "\n")`?

Comment: Achei que não daria mesmo, mas não custava tentar, né? Pensei em outra solução para o meu problema. Obrigado, pessoal!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Para tal tarefa terá que calcular o boundbox da font family e mensurar as proporções por escala de acordo com a largura do elemento HTML.

Com isso poderá ter um resultado bem próximo e as vezes exato, mas nunca se pode confiar.

Um dos motivos em evitar esse tipo de solução é que não terá o controle do lado cliente. Um usuário pode não possuir a font-family e então o browser assume a próxima da lista ou uma font padrão a qual provavelmente terá medidas diferentes.

> [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Se ainda assim quer prosseguir, pode começar pelas funções da biblioteca GD:
http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagettfbbox.php

Exemplo prático:

```
/*
Largura do elemento HTML <p>
Defina em pontos (pt), não em pixels (px)
O motivo é que ficará complicado se definir em pixels porque a função imagettfbbox() retorna em pontos (pt).
*/
$p_width = 100; // em pontos, não em pixels

/*
Local da fonte:
*/
$font = './Arial_n.ttf';

/*
O texto
*/
$data = 'lorem ipsum a
sa odfdsgoi jgiodfg diofgjd foigd a
d fgidfogjdfio g';

/*
O primeiro parâmetro é o tamanho do texto, aqui definido em 16.
O segundo é o ângulo. Definido em zero pois será exibido na horizontal.
O terceiro é o arquivo da font-family. Aqui usei "Arial Normal".
O quarto é o texto.
*/
$bbox = imagettfbbox(16, 0, $font, $data);

/*
Exibe a largura maior encontrada.
Nesse exemplo, é 306pt
*/
echo 'texto largura: '.$bbox[2].'pt'.PHP_EOL;

/*
Arredonde o valor da divisão para cima pois se passar 0.01pt, indica que ultrapassou a linha corrente.
*/
echo 'linhas estimadas: '.ceil($bbox[2] / $p_width);
```

Isso ainda é insuficiente pois os idiomas baseados no alfabeto romano possuem espaçamentos entre as palavras. As medidas que o script acima mostra desconsidera isso e pode estar quebrando uma palavra. Se isso não é o que deseja, terá que criar uma implementação que identifique os espaçamentos. Não é muito difícil, mas é um pouco complicado. O exemplo acima é o suficiente.

Comment: Eu vou incluir a fonte no documento. Isso ajuda, não?

Comment: Também não garante mas é mais seguro. Eu digo que não garante porque também pode ocorrer da fonte não ser carregada. Aí fica tudo zuado.

Comment: Vou estudar essa função que você falou. Pensei em usá-la para calcular o tamanho de cada palavra, e quando a soma delas (mais os espaços) atingir ou passar o width informado, a função incrementa +1 ao $linhas. Será que funciona?

Comment: Sim. É bem simples. Vou colocar um exemplo fácil